# Hacer un condicional que valide la primera posición de un string

Tags: python, string, if

Necesito hacer un `if` que valide si la primera letra de un string es `T`.

Hice algo como lo siguiente:

```
NombreForma = T-000000-0
if docjson['NombreForma'] != "T" and docjson['SistemaOrigen'] == "P":
```

Pero obvio no sirve a menos que la `T` esté sola.

Comment: `if str(docjson['NombreForma'])[0] != 'T' and docjson['SistemaOrigen'] == 'P':` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que `docjson['NombreForma']` y `docjson['SistemaOrigen']` sean strings, puedes usar el método [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
if docjson['NombreForma'].startswith('T') and docjson['SistemaOrigen'].startswith('P'):
    ....
```

También, puedes consultar el elemento de cada cadena mediante su índice:

```
if docjson['NombreForma'][0] == 'T' and docjson['SistemaOrigen'][0] == 'P':
    ...
```

Pero usar índices te puede dar problemas si, por ejemplo, tienes una string vacía:

```
>>> s = ''
>>> s[0] == 'T'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
>>> s = 'T00000'
>>> s[0] == 'T'
True
```

Una opción, si deseas usar los índices, es cortando (slicing) la cadena:

```
>>> s = ''
>>> s[:1] # El primer elemento
''
>>> s[:1] == 'T'
False
>>> s = 'T00000'
>>> s[:1] == 'T'
True
```

A diferencia del método `startswith` que simplemente te retornará verdadero o falso:

```
>>> s = ''
>>> s.startswith('T')
False
>>> s = 'T00000'
>>> s.startswith('T')
True
```